# Re-use a hardcoded value in multiple function calls in PostgreSQL query

Tags: postgresql, sql-function

I have some functions in PostgreSQL 9.0 that return table results. The idea behind these is to return the data as it was at a certain time, eg.

```
CREATE FUNCTION person_asof(effective_time timestamp with time zone)
RETURNS SETOF person
...

CREATE FUNCTION pgroup_asof(effective_time timestamp with time zone)
RETURNS SETOF pgroup
...
```

I can query them almost as if they were tables, with joins and all:

```
SELECT *
FROM pgroup_asof('2011-01-01') g
JOIN person_asof('2011-01-01') p
ON g.id = p.group_id
```

This works fine, but is there any trick I can use to specify the effective time just once?

I tried to do something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT '2010-04-12'::timestamp ts) effective,
pgroup_asof(effective.ts) g
JOIN person_asof(effective.ts) p
ON g.id = p.group_id
```

...but that fails with **ERROR:  function expression in FROM cannot refer to other relations of same query level** and putting the main query into a sub-query doesn't help, either.

Comment: You could prepare a statement using one $1 param (timestamp with time zone). I don't see any other solution to this.

Answer (score 3):

This is something I have wanted to do in the past as well but does not look like it is possible yet, but there may be [hope](http://rhaas.blogspot.com/2010/04/finding-our-way-to-lateral.html) on the horizon.

Comment: +1 Interesting read, thanks. Looks like LATERAL didn't make it into 9.1 - perhaps 9.2? My problem, however, doesn't necessarily need LATERAL, because I only want to re-use a constant, not a row returned from a query.