# Function returning table in WHERE clause, how to use result of query as parameter?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I've got a PL/pgSQL function that return a table whose definition is as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_movement_aggregation(movement_table varchar,place_table varchar,geom varchar,point_gid varchar, radius numeric DEFAULT 20000, inArea geometry DEFAULT NULL)
RETURNS TABLE(place_i integer) AS
-- actual code here
```

Now I would like to use this function by using a geometry (the `inArea` parameter) that I get from another table. When I try the following query:

```
WITH x AS (
  SELECT wkb_geometry from tha_adm1 
  WHERE name_1 = 'Ubon Ratchathani' LIMIT 1
)
SELECT g.* 
FROM x,
get_movement_aggregation('movements','places','geom','place_id',14000,x.wkb_geometry)
```

I get the following error:

`ERROR: function expression in FROM cannot refer to other relations of same query level`

It does make sense as I indeed refer to `x` in both parts of the `FROM`clause.

The subquery returns the following:

```
+----------------------------------+
|   |  wkb_geometry                |
|   |  geometry(MultiPolygon,4326) |
+---+------------------------------+
| 1 | some very long number here   |
+---+------------------------------+
```

And I just use this parameter to filter the list of records I am working with in the function. One solution would be to create a temporary table with the filtered records and feed to the function but if there is a way to do that with a subquery, that would be great.

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: Might actually be similar to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6687643/re-use-a-hardcoded-value-in-multiple-function-calls-in-postgresql-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not this:

```
WITH x AS (
  SELECT wkb_geometry from tha_adm1 
  WHERE name_1 = 'Ubon Ratchathani' LIMIT 1
)
SELECT 
get_movement_aggregation('movements','places',
                         'geom','place_id',14000,x2.wkb_geometry)
FROM (SELECT * FROM x) as x2
```

Or a simpler form, without the `WITH` clause:

```
SELECT 
get_movement_aggregation('movements','places',
                         'geom','place_id',14000,x2.wkb_geometry)
FROM (SELECT wkb_geometry from tha_adm1 
  WHERE name_1 = 'Ubon Ratchathani' LIMIT 1) as x2
```

Or if you prefer to have explicit fields rather than a function call in the final select list:

```
SELECT g.* FROM 
 (SELECT get_movement_aggregation('movements','places',
                                  'geom','place_id',14000,x2.wkb_geometry)
    FROM (SELECT wkb_geometry from tha_adm1 
           WHERE name_1 = 'Ubon Ratchathani' LIMIT 1) as x2
 ) as g;
```

Comment: Answer accepted. So the trick was to put the function call in the `SELECT`... Was not really familiar with functions returning tables. Merci mille fois!!!

Answer (score 1):

This form of the query is called `LATERAL` in the SQL standard.
Support for such queries will be available in PostgreSQL 9.3, you can find an [excellent review here](http://www.depesz.com/2012/08/19/waiting-for-9-3-implement-sql-standard-lateral-subqueries/) by @depesz.

Before that you will have to use subqueries, @Daniel outlined a bunch of possibilities.

Comment: Yeah, I've read this on another answer and I've read the review too. Thank you! @Daniel helped to get the result I wanted.